# How is serverless.com related to AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless, serverless.com

I created free account in serverless.com. Then I installed serverless locally. Next I deployed simple "hello world" [function](https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/quick-start)

It works. REST Get returns as expected.
But where this lambda function is deployed?
It is not visible in AWS console nor return by the following command

```
aws lambda list-functions       
{
    "Functions": []
}
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Why is the AWS CLI is not listing my function?

```sh
# make sure you are looking at the right region
# if region not specified, the cli will use the .aws/config default
aws lambda list-functions  --region eu-west-1
```

#### How is serverless.com related to AWS?

The Serverless Framework, which is independent of AWS, describes itself as *"Zero-friction development tooling for auto-scaling apps on AWS Lambda"*.  It is one way of many to deploy serverless components to AWS.

Answer (score -1):

Serverless.com (https://www.serverless.com/)  along with AWS SAM(https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/) is the two approach we can take advantage of building a Serverless Architecture for Projects.

Serverless mainly have a serverless.yml and it does use a cloudformation stack to deploy.